# What is causing my high packet loss?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have been cursed with bad Wi-Fi for years, and I've lately tried to overcompensate for that by creating a wireless mesh network, adding two [Eero Pro 6e](https://eero.com/shop/eero-pro-6e) in bridge mode, each with wired gigabit Ethernet connection back to my existing router. Roughly:

[image]

Lately my packet loss for some(?) stations has been through the roof, 40-70%. For example, between Stations A and B, both on the same Eero and connected to the 5 GHz network:

```
17 packets transmitted, 7 packets received, 58.8% packet loss
```

It's similarly bad pinging an Internet host from one of these two stations. Packet loss also does not significantly change if I test the Eeros in isolation.

I know that my wired connections are all fine: I can ping an Internet host and the two access points from the router with good speeds and no loss.

The kicker: The (non-Eero) router device also broadcasts a legacy 2.4 GHz network with a separate SSID, but the same subnet. If I connect Station A to the legacy network, and then ping Station B (on one of the Eeros), packet loss dramatically improves:

```
27 packets transmitted, 27 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
```

It's almost like the stations and the Eero APs don't get along. But both Stations A and B in this case are recent MacBooks running the same OS. There's no obvious misconfiguration like the MTU being set wrong.

I live in an apartment building with many access points around me, but they have weak signal strengths except for my immediately adjacent neighbors'. My stations are physically close to the APs which are out in the open.

---

I ran one more test, which was to eliminate the separate router and run the Eero in router mode. Packet loss between Station A and Station B reduced to negligible levels.

So it is possibly some interplay between:

1. The Eero being in bridge mode with an upstream router device.
2. Station A and B both being connected to the Eero simultaneously, **or** routing between two hosts when both are not directly connected to the router.

Comment: try a traceroute to your gateway and see if any additional hops are present and responsible for high latency in ms